# How do I install mod_wsgi in Apache for python 3.5 on CentOS 7 if apxs2 is missing?

Tags: apache-2.4, python, centos7, mod-wsgi

I am currently trying to install mod_wsgi 4.4.21 into Apache 2.4 for a Python 3.5 web server on CentOS 7.

Under "Configuring The Source Code" in the [Quick Installation Guide](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Configuring_The_Source_Code), it says this:

> On some Linux distributions, such as SUSE and CentOS, it will be necessary to use the "--with-apxs" option and specify either "/usr/sbin/apxs2-worker" or "/usr/sbin/apxs2-prefork".

As far as I can tell, those are supposed to come with the httpd-devel package. I have that installed already:

```
# rpm -qa | grep httpd
httpd-tools-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64
httpd-manual-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.noarch
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64
httpd-devel-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64
```

However I don't have `apxs2-worker` or `apxs2-prefork` in `/usr/sbin`:

```
# ls /usr/sbin/apxs*
ls: cannot access /usr/sbin/apxs*: No such file or directory
```

However, I do have `apxs` in `/usr/bin`. Can I just use that, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: At first glance,  yes.; `/usr/bin/apxs` sounds like a correct location.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, I ended up using `/usr/bin/apxs` and it seems to work fine.